# Using dataset.persisit() and dataset.unpersist() in Java

Tags: apache-spark, caching, persist

I have a Spark Dataset `dataset`.
I need to do `.collectAsList()` for Each column of Dataset.
How can I use `.persist()` and `.unpersist()` to avoid huge time for operations?

Since I am new , I am not sure how do I make use of the persist functions.
Do I need to assign this to a dataset as `dataset=dataset.persist();` or just a `dataset.persist()` would do the trick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you just want to cache the dataset, then use dataset.persist(). Similarly, dataset.unpersist() to remove all blocks for it from memory.